# How to disable a certain code from another page?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I was wondering how to disable a certain code in a php page using another page, which will have options of enable and disable ?
of course temporary disabling, not permanent, so we can enable it later ?

any Ideas about that ?

and thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Yepp, you can do a call from another page and submit a special parameter which will cause the server to create/change a configuration file on the server. This configuration file needs to get read every time the page is requested.
Depending on the configuration a feature of that page will be enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: my bad - i thought i read of 2 files, but you were asking for two pages -> nevermind

file a:

```
   [..]
   define('SHOW_BLOCK', TRUE);
   [..]
```

file b:

```
  [..]
  if (SHOW_BLOCK) {
      [..]
  }
  [..]
```

constants are global